# Trying to print a range from 0 to x, replacing even digits with a word, and getting None for my last digit

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming and am taking an online school course on Python, and the assignment is to count from 0 to a number (x) but skipping 0, without spaces or lines between the numbers, but also replacing even numbers with the word 'tomato.'

Looking for an answer similar to: `01tomato3tomato5tomato7tomato9tomato`

The instructions say to not use print statements inside the body of the function. Not to print, but build string and then return it. I'm not sure how to do this without them.

The assignment states to not use "advanced" coding and to just use the basics we have learned, and I am trying to use this code but I keep getting the word 'None' for my last number instead of the number or word to no avial.

**Code:**

```
def soup(x):
    for i in range(x):
        if i>0 and i%2==0:
            print ('tomato',end='')
        else:
            print (i,end='')
```

I have searched for the past few hours and can not seem to find basic solutions or a good answer. Thanks for any help.

Comment: How are you calling your code? This seems to do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Maybe you mean that there is an off-by-one error? If you want to print all numbers from zero including `x`, you need to do `for i in range(x + 1):` because the end argument for range is *exclusive*. Also, are you by any chance calling your code like this: `print(soup(10))`? Because that is why you are getting `None`. A function without a return value implicitly returns `None`. You just need to call it like this: `soup(10)`. Also, to skip zero, just use `for i in range(1, x + 1)` instead of checking for `i > 0`

Comment: do you run it as `soup(10)` or as `print(soup(10))` ? Do you run it in Python Shell or normally `python script.py` ?

Comment: It wants me to include 0 in my return.
If I was needing to go to 10, it would want: 01tomato3tomato5tomato7tomato9tomato
But I am getting:
01tomato3tomato5tomato7tomato9none

And if I change the range to n+1, it gives me:
01tomato3tomato5tomato7tomato9tomatoNone

Comment: I am running it from inside Pyzo (what they want us to use).

If I just do soup(10) it actually does give me the right answer, so thank you. I guess I did not need the print() function. But is there a "prettier" way of writing this code or is this good enough? 1/3 of the grade is the cleanliness of the code. Also, how do I mark the good answers I'm getting to give credit to you all? I'm new to the site as well. Thanks!

Comment: You get NONE because your function does not *RETURN* anything.

Comment: I just read the assignment's comment and it says to not use print statements inside the body of the function. Not to print, but build a string and then return it. I'm no sure how to do this without print statements.

Comment: Also, what is the point of the `end=''`? In Python 2.7, you don't need that. I know you're using 3.x, but try removing it.

Comment: @VISQL It is to prevent a space or line in between each returned number or word.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga adding +1 fixed that, thank you. But now it wants me to do this same assignment without using print statements in the function. I have no clue how to do that, honestly.

Comment: @furas taking out print() fixed an issue as well, now I have to do this assignment without using print statements in the function. I am now lost.

Comment: do you mean `result = ""` and later `result += 'tomato'` or `result += str(i)` , and at end `return result` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def foo(n):
  # we are going build string instead of printing
  # start with 0 as it will be our base case.
  s = '0'
  # loop to n
  for i in range(n):
    # skip 0
    if i > 0:
      # if even, add to s, tomato
      if i % 2 == 0:
        s += 'tomato'
      else:
      # else, add i, but cast it to string
        s += str(i)
  return s

print(foo(10))

def foo_cleanup(n):
  # we are going build string instead of printing
  # start with 0 as it will be our base case.
  s = '0'
  # loop to n, skipping 0 all together
  # might look like a small clean up, but consider n > 1 billion
  # that is 1 billion redundant checks
  for i in range(1,n):
    # if even, add to s, tomato
    if i % 2 == 0:
      s += 'tomato'
    else:
    # else, add i, but cast it to string
      s += str(i)
  return s

# list comprehension, not always best, but useful
def foo_advanced(n):
  s = '0'+''.join(['tomato' if i % 2 ==0 else str(i) for i in range(1,n)])
  return s
print(foo_advanced(10))
```

Comment: He didn't return the integers as strings, but as integers. This solution therefore, does not have the same nor intended output. It's close though. Maybe use a list instead.

Comment: Have no clue what you're saying.

Comment: When you print 1 is that 1 a string, or not?

Comment: @taesu This was perfect, thank you for the reply and the explanation comments. It solved my problem and I learned something new.

Comment: @billyeast283 you're welcome. make sure you fully understand the answer, that's why I invested my time writing those comments! c'ya

Answer (score 1):

Make a variable `foo` equal to `""` and concatenate instead of printing, followed by a return.

```
def soup(x):
    foo = ""
    for i in range(x):
        if i>0 and i%2==0:
            foo += "tomato"
        else:
            foo += str(i)
    return foo
```

Comment: He didn't return the integers as strings, but as integers. This solution therefore, does not have the same nor intended output. It's close though. Maybe use a list instead.

Comment: @VISQL I'm sorry, your statement seems unclear to me, who is "He"? billyeast did not have a return statement at all. billyeast also stated the goal was build a "string and then return it". Why is a list a more correct return?

Answer (score 0):

```
''.join(str(x) if x == 0 or x % 2 else 'tomato' for x in range(0, 10))
```

Answer (score -1):

This

```
def soup(x):
    for i in range(x):
        if i>0 and i%2==0:
            print 'tomato' #,end=''
        else:
            print i #,end=''
```

gives this

```
0
1
tomato
3
tomato
5
tomato
7
tomato
9
```

when you execute this

```
soup(10)
```

in Python 2.7

Comment: I comment out that `end=''` stuff since it has no use for me.

Comment: I actually needed them all on one line, with no spaces between them, like this: 01tomato3tomato5tomato7tomato9tomato
Thanks anyway, another comment helped me in my Python 3.5.